# Is there a way to tie only certain audio output to an external bluetooth speaker?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

I am using a Dell XPS 8930 and Lubuntu 20.04LTS, and I have never had bluetooth in my computer before.  It's fun, and I have a nice bluetooth external speaker...but I'd like to have music only playing in the room while I keep my gaming and web audio on my headphones only.  Is that possible?  For example, send ONLY my Spotify audio to the external speaker, while keeping everything else on the headphones?

Thank you!

Comment: You can probably configure this with pulseaudio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install "pulseaudio volume control"  :
`sudo apt install pavucontrol`
Launch it from "multimedia" menu.
In the "playing" tab, you can select sound device for each running application.

Comment: Thank you.  I've gotten that far now, but unfortunately, the only sound that I get is what's coming out of the bluetooth speaker.  I'm able to see the sound vibrating in the Pulse view bar, but no sound in my headphones or computer speakers...only sound when I switch to the Bluetooth speaker.  I feel like there's (maybe?) another step to this I'm missing?  Do I have to have Pulse up first before running the bluetooth connection.

Comment: Nevermind...I didn't see that the mute for the desktop had been activated (perhaps by the Bluetooth when I started?).  Anyway, as soon as I clicked it, everything worked exactly like you said!  Thank you!